# What is the best way to query these tables

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, subquery, inner-join

I have 4 tables,
I'm trying to get all the chats that belong to the user with the id of 1, I can do that shown in the query below however I'm unsure of how efficient it is.

Secondly, I want to make this query a bit more complex by also getting all the other users which are in the chats along with the user that has the id of 1 however I'm unsure how to do this.

```
select * from chat_users left join chats on chat_users.chat_id = chats.id left join users on chat_users.user_id = users.id where user_id = 1
```

1. Users - id, username
2. Chats - id, chatname
3. chat_users id, user_id, chat_id
4. Posts - post, id, text

E.g.

If we imagine chats table as:

```
id : 1 | chatname : FirstChat
```

Chat_users as

```
id : 1 | user_id : 1 | chat_id : 1
id : 2 | user_id : 2 | chat_id : 1
```

Users as

```
id: 1 | username: firstUser
id: 2 | username: secondUser
```

I eventually want to end up with a query that returns all the chats that user1 is involved in along with the data for the other users in them chats however I'm not sure how I would do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to phrase the query:

```
select c.*, u.*
from chat_users cu
inner join chats c on c.id = cu.chat_id
inner join users u on u.id = cu.user_id
where exists (
    select 1 from chat_users cu1 where cu1.chat_id = cu.chat_id and cu1.user_id = 1
)
```

Comment: Hi can you inform me what <> does in the query, i have used them separately as less than and greater than but never together

Comment: @Minstrels: it means "different than". That's the contrary of `=`. In other languages, it is sometimes phrased as `!=`.

Comment: Hi, so if I take off 'u.id <> 1' it would give me the results including user 1?

Comment: @Minstrels: you want users that are in the same chat as user 1, excluding user 1. The subquery brings the chats of user 1. The `<>` condition excludes user 1 from the results.

Comment: What if I want results to show all the chats that user 1 is in along with all the other users in each chat but I also want user1 in the results. So firstchat:user1 , firstchat:user2

Comment: @Minstrels: ok, so just remove condition `u.id <> 1`.

Comment: Can you edit it from your answer so I can accept it please?

Comment: 'where cu1.chat_id = c.chat_id' should probably be c.id in case someone else stumbles accross this and tries the query along with the tables in the original post. Thanks alot for the help !

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you just want an aggregation:

```
select chat_id,
       group_concat( case when cu.user_id <> 1 then user_id end) as other_users
from chat_users cu
group by chat_id
having sum( cu.user_id = 1 ) > 0;
```

This returns the chat id and the users -- which is what you are asking for.  You can join in other information if you want.

Comment: Hi , I seem to get the following error : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') as other_users
from chat_users cu
group by chat_id
having sum( cu.user_id =' at line 2

Comment: @Minstrels . . . `case` needs `end`.

Comment: Hi can you give me an example of how I would join in the other information for example if I also wanted the username information?

Comment: Hi, I have accepted the other post but your post was also along the right lines however it was just too complex for me as I wasn't sure how I would add in the other information for each user id for example if I wanted the username information for each user.

Comment: @Minstrels . . . I answered because I thought this was simpler.  As the OP, though, that is your decision and GMB's answer is fine except the users are on different rows when I figured you would want them on a single row for each chat.